# Setting up an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to authenticate in my own Authentication Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

**Context:**

We have a monster **ASP.NET MVC 5/Framework 4.5** application that is planned to be divided in several others, so each new application will deal with a specific business domain instead of many. All those applications together will provide the same functionalities and services that are provided today by the existing single application.

We plan to use our own OAuth server to provide authentication and authorization for all the new smaller applications, so the very same users that use the current large application will have the same rights in the same functionality.

Currently we use Windows Authentication mixed with a secondary custom structure to establish what a certain user can do. We have our own role provider to generate the roles assigned to the users. When a certain controller action asks for the list of roles af a certain user, our role provider search in our custom structure and provide those roles, following specific business rules that make sense in our application.

We understand that the same rules that establish the set of the roles assigned to a certain user will be moved to our OAuth server.

We understand that the role-based security will be replaced by a claim-based security.

We understand that we will stop testing for roles and start testing for claims.

We understand that the first step of this refactoring should be add external authentication in our current large application and then start to break it into parts so we will have our new ecosystem.

**Question:**

*How to change my current large application so it authenticate and authorize requests by using the new OAuth server instead by itself?*

**Note:**

I´ve read a lot of blog posts but so far I couldn´t find a simple code sample that shows me what to do to instruct my application to go for an authentication/authorization token in my OAuth server and use it to grant or deny the access to a given controller action.

Comment: Your architecture will depend to some extend on the version of ASP.NET you are using now and whether you'll be changing it for the future application.  Auth frameworks have been undergoing a great deal of transformation in every edition of ASP.NET since 2009.  What version of ASP.NET MVC will you be using for this?

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, I see you are targeting MVC 5. Look at this blog and download the open source Identity Server with the samples.  You may be using a different identity server, but the way ASP.NET pipeline hooks into the authentication/authorization should be the same

http://leastprivilege.com/